# iphone phonegap change url

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova

Is there any way of changing the url for phonegap on iPhone/iPad? In Android you can simply use `loadUrl` to change the url but a function like this doesn't seem to exist on iPhone/iPad.

I know there is a 'dirty' hack by using a redirect... but this rules out the use of the phonegap api on the external website which you are including in phonegap (via redirect).

Any help on this guys?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did the answer below help ? If yes, then accept it. If no then provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the url when you click on a link you just need to do :

```
window.location="page.html";
```

OR

```
window.location.href="page.html";
```